# Error opening .jpg with readJPEG in R because of accent in path

Tags: r

I'm working in a directory where the path have one string with accent (C:\Users\Zá\Documents).

I set this path as defalt and I already use this same path to others functions like read.csv and it works fine.

When I tried to use this path in readJPG I get an error message.

I alredy tried to use *normalizePath*, but the error continues.

I am using UTF-8 as default text encoding.

```r
setwd("C:\Users\Zá\Documents\")
img1<-readJPEG("~\gd.jpg", native = T )
```

Error in readJPEG("~\gd.jpg", native = T):unable to open C:\Users\ZÃ¡\Documents\gd.jpg

Does anyone have an idea how can I fix it ?

Thanks all.

Comment: Have you tried setting the locale to match that UTF-8 encoding? You can do that by running
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "en_US.UTF-8")

Comment: @JulioP.C. thaks for your help. I already set UTF-8 as defalt text encoding in RStudio Global Options. However, when I tried to execute Sys, R continued to return me the same error: _Error in readJPEG ("~ / gd.jpg", native = T):
   unable to open C: /Users/ZÃ¡/gd.jpg_